# Not able to get serialized Array of Kendo UI Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have a simple form, where I have a form element with one input type and button.

When I am click button, I am trying to get form data using

```
var fData = $("#test").serializeArray();
```

However for some reason, I am not able to get any values of form.

What could be the reason for this?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ukC/63/)

Comment: Did you try ..serialize() ?;

Comment: @JohnGr. Yes, but didn't work.

Comment: You serialize the input with ID="test" ?

Comment: All fields are not serialized. The `serializeArray()` doesn't serialize buttons and input without `type` attribute.

Comment: @Maxime just to be clear, only the `name` attribute is required. A `type` of `text` is assumed if the attribute is not provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues. Firstly, the `input` has no `name` attribute, so it cannot be serialized. Secondly, you create the variable called `fData`, but log `fdata` - JS is case sensitive. Finally the form is being submit in the usual method when the button is clicked which means processing will be prevented after the first `alert`. To prevent this you can change the button to be a standard type, instead of a submit button:

```
<form id="test" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input id="val" name="foo" />
    </p>
    <button class="k-button" id="rset" type="button">submit</button>
</form>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ukC/68/)

Or alternatively you can set the code to run under the `submit` event of the form, and use `preventDefault` to stop the standard form submission:

```
$("#test").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('ok');
    var fData = $(this).serializeArray();
    alert('rData  ' + fData);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ukC/69/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, it was rather silly that I didn't add name attribute for input. Appreciated.